# How to work something

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if this sounds right?

> Do you know how to work the projector?

Comment: Hi Zara, welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid proof reading questions are off topic, as stated in the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Zara, if you want to improve this question, please edit it and ask about what specifically bothers you about that sentence. Please be aware that we expect people to look words up in the dictionary first, in case you are wondering about [various uses of the word "work"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=define%3A+work&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=3c3&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=work&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=eP3PTumkMsLZgAfW-cTcDQ&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=c142d81856469c2c&biw=1422&bih=727).

Answer (score 3):

> I'll learn to work the saxophone/I'll play just what I feel [Steely
>   Dan, *Deacon Blues*]

Certainly. From M-W:

> **work**, *noun*. 4 : to set or keep in motion, operation, or activity [work cattle in a roundup] : *cause to operate or produce* [a pump
>   worked by hand] [work a quarry] [work farmland]